# example for permutizer group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

permutizer of a subgroup H of G is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of G that permute with H. You can help us give an example?
[image]

Comment: What does "permute with H" mean? Did you mean "commute"?

Comment: Ask specific, for which subgroup of which group you want to calculate permutizer. Otherwise in any cyclic group , permutizer of any subgroup $H$ is Group itself.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes it does mean commute in the sense $KH=HK$ but unfortunately this is often referred to as "permuting with" in the literature.

Answer (score 0):

For an example where the permutizer is larger than the normalizer of the subgroup, you could take a subgroup of order $2$ in $S_3$, where the permutizer is the whole group.

Comment: very thanksssss